# ASP.NET Calling defined JS-function with RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, call, invoke

In ASP.NET we are calling defined js-functions with the:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "", "JSFuncNameHere();", true);
```

I wonder:

- Why there isn't any method, which has a name like: Page.ClientScript.CallJSScript("someJSFunc");
- Why does the upper-method require the reflection method GetType() ? Something isn't defined at runtime, is it?
- Why do I need the 2nd argument `key`? As I have tested, I can left it empty and the existed JS-function shall be called.

Answer (score 1):

- Why there isn't any method, which has a name like: Page.ClientScript.CallJSScript("someJSFunc");

Probably because this is more generic solution, since by just adding 2 characters you get the same result and if you need you can add arguments and anything else.

- Why does the upper-method require the reflection method GetType() ? Something isn't defined at runtime, is it?
- Why do I need the 2nd argument key? As I have tested, I can left it empty and the existed JS-function shall be called.

For both of these the same reason - the method will detect if you run the same script multiple times and in such case, call it just once. The two arguments are the means how it identifies duplicates - a key is not sufficient since another class in a different library might be using the same key - so you need to pass in the type of your own class to ensure that the script is executed when you want it to.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the MSDN documentation for `RegisterStartupScript` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx - provides the answers for points 2 and 3 in "Remarks". When trying to determine the purpose of method parameters, MSDN should *always* be your first stop :)